# App crashes after tapping the home button and then returning to the same activity by clicking the app icon

Tags: java, android, crash, setcontentview, onsaveinstancestate

When I launch my activity after having installed it, it runs fine; then if I tap the home button of the device (I'm using Lenovo TB3 tablet), and then launch the activity again by clicking on its icon, the app crashes and relaunch itself automatically.
I am not able to figure out the issue.

My Stack Trace:

```
App has crashed
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already added!
```

I have checked the life cycle of my application,
when I press back button of my device following methods were called

1. onCreate()
2. onStart()
3. onResume()

And when I pressed the back button following methods were called

1. onPause()
2. onStop()
3. onDestroy()

And, Same above methods were called when pressing the home button.
Then why the app crashes by clicking on it's icon after pressing the home button?
MyActivity Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate:savedInstanceState" +savedInstanceState);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);//At this line crash happens
    setContentView(R.layout.basic_activity_concept_home);
    Logger.d(TAG, "onCreate: ");
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    student = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Constants.JSON_KEY_STUDENT);
    pageIndex = 0;
    pager.addOnPageChangeListener(onPageChangeListener);
    setPresenter(presenter);
    showProgress(R.string.getting_concept_activities);
}
```

Code That calls the above activity:

```
@OnClick(R.id.btn_concept_basic_activities)
    public void goToConceptActivities() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BasicActivityConceptHome.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.JSON_KEY_STUDENT, student);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

I didn't find any workaround of this issue.
Any help would be much appreciated. :)
Thanks :)

Comment: you will need to share the entire activity. This wont help figure out what is happening.

Comment: share your home button event

Comment: I had a similar issue because i had code in onResume that recalled the onCreate() and when you first instantiate the activity somewhere along the way, after onCreate(), onResume() is also called.

Comment: There can be more than the issue stated earlier, take a look at this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: Another idea, if you say it works well after intsalling it (from androidStudio i suppose), then the reason it is crashing when opening from icon might be because of an intent sent by the system. Check also if you have any onNewIntent() or callback of sort.

Comment: @AlexandruSandu onResume() method is not present in my code!

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if your activity is declared as **singleTask** or **singleInstance** in Manifest.

Comment: I have not use singleTask or singleInstance in my manifest @sela

Comment: Are you calling some of methods attachBaseContext, setActionBar? Can you provide us in your post code of activity?

Comment: No such methods are there.